# get weekly sum data from table using sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I tried some queries but non will work for me,i have to show app data in listview from sqlite table which having duplicates by sum total this week.

query i tried

1. `String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_APPDATA + " WHERE DATE( date_time ) >= DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')";`
2. `"SELECT strftime('%Y-%W', date_time ) as date_time, sum(app_data) FROM "+TABLE_APPDATA+ " GROUP BY date_time order by app_data desc"`

`Table app_data`

```
------------------------------------------
app_uid | date_time | app_name | app_data|
10118   | 12-6-2016 |Google App| 200     |
10158   | 12-6-2016 | Youtube  | 300     |
10001   | 12-6-2016 | updater  | 100     |
10158   | 13-6-2016 | Youtube  | 500     |
------------------------------------------
```

Here duplicates are there have to sum app_data i.e Youtube 800, any query for that would be thankful

Answer (score 3):

Your second version is pretty close.  The problem is the naming of the columns.  Try this:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%W', date_time ) as date_time, sum(app_data)
FROM "+TABLE_APPDATA+ "
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%W', date_time ) 
ORDER BY app_data desc;
```

Or, if you want to use the column alias, give it a name different from any column:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%W', date_time ) as yyyyww, sum(app_data)
FROM "+TABLE_APPDATA+ "
GROUP BY yyyyww
ORDER BY app_data desc;
```

Comment: tried first one Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by `strtime(%W, date_time)`. This will give you a week number and you can use it to get all records for the week and `sum` them.

Comment: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.  And by the way date_time is in string format do i have to change in date format

Comment: This points to a totally different problem, related to reading from your cursor after executing the query. To check if the query works, you can use sqlviewer to extract the database and run queries against it.